# Change resources available to the processes from Python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

Is there a way to change resources available to a running process from `Python`? Namely I would like to change `Max open files` `soft`:`hard` limit.

I know I can use `ulimit -n 1024000` and spawn process from that shell, but that would require stopping that process beforehand.

I'm also aware of `prlimit`, but it's not available in `Wheezy 7.6` with `util-linux 2.20.1-5.3`.

Python `resource` module apparently allows changing limits just for itself...

I have found the following [blog article](https://gregchapple.com/updating-ulimit-on-running-linux-process/), which explains how to do it with `gdb` and I'm just hoping that something similar exists in `Python`.

Essentially I think I'm asking how to make `setrlimit` system-call for a running process from the Python program.

Answer (score 2):

Take another look at the `resource` library. The function [`resource.prlimit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html#resource.prlimit) takes a `pid` as its first argument, and raises `ProcessLookupError` if a process by that ID cannot be found. So I believe it's exactly what you're looking for.

> [resource.prlimit(pid, resource[, limits])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html#resource.prlimit)
>
> Combines [setrlimit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html#resource.setrlimit) and [getrlimit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html#resource.getrlimit) in one function and supports to get and set the resources limits of an arbitrary process. If pid is 0, then the call applies to the current process. [...]
>
> When `limits` is not given the function returns the resource limit of the process pid. When `limits` is given the resource limit of the process is set and the former resource limit is returned.

The catch is that this function is not present in Python 2.7. Hopefully you can dip your toes in python 3 for this one task.

Comment: Sorry, I perhaps tagged my question incorrectly. It should also work from `python2.7`, hence I updated question tags. Though thank you, it's good to know `python3` has this functionality.

Comment: I just noticed that it's not available from python 2.7. Editing.

Comment: You should just switch to python 3 anyway, for lots of other reasons... :-)